# How to get the value in Ember Select by Below code

Tags: ember.js, handles

Handle Bars Is below :- 
   {{#each category in controller}}

```
 {{view Ember.Select
    contentBinding="App.testsController.content"
    optionLabelPath="content.category"

    selectionBinding="content.myVal"

 }}    

{{view Ember.Select
   contentBinding="App.testsController.content"

   optionLabelPath="content.type"  
}}   

{{view Ember.Select
   contentBinding="App.testsController.content"      
   selectionBinding="content.myVal"
}} 

controller is :-
App.TestsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  content: []
});

model is :- 
App.Test = Ember.Object.extend(
 category: null
 type: null
 #operands: null
#defaults: null
)
```

In the view I'm not able to get the value category and type. It is not displaying. How to fix the problem?

Comment: Pleas read the doc here along with the code. https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/controls/select.js  I have added a relevant part below

Answer (score 2):

Are you grabbing your controller through a router? If so, you may specifically need to call contentBinding: 'App.router.testsController.content'

Also, your selectionBinding should read 'controller.myVal' instead of 'content.myVal'.

Comment: Cool! If my suggestion worked, then would you kindly mark it as the answer? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to [Git hub doc](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-handlebars/lib/controls/select.js) , below is a relevant part.

Alternatively, you can control selection through the underlying objects
used to render each object providing a `selectionBinding`. When the selected
`<option>` is changed, the property path provided to `selectionBinding`
will be updated to match the content object of the rendered `<option>`
element:

```
App.controller = Ember.Object.create({
selectedPerson: null,
content: [
Ember.Object.create({firstName: "Yehuda", id: 1}),
Ember.Object.create({firstName: "Tom", id: 2})
]
});
```

---

```
{{view Ember.Select
contentBinding="App.controller.content"
optionValuePath="content.id"
optionLabelPath="content.firstName"
selectionBinding="App.controller.selectedPerson"}}
```

Would result in the following HTML with a selected option:

```
<select class="ember-select">
<option value>Please Select</option>
<option value="1">Yehuda</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected">Tom</option>
</select>
```